# Castle ActiveRecord Lazy-Loading NOT Working

Tags: c#, nhibernate, activerecord, repository-pattern, castle-activerecord

I need some help in understanding this issue. I'm using the repository
pattern with ActiveRecordMediator. I've enabled the session scope http
module, marked my classes with the ActiveRecord(Lazy = true).

The problem is that each time I perform a FindAll or SlicedFindAll,
the mediator returns a collection of initialized elements instead of
proxies. Could someone point me out in the right direction?

This is my repository:

```
public interface IEntityRepository<TEntity>
{
    IList<TEntity> FindAll(int page, int pageSize, out int resultCount);
}

public class EntityRepository<TEntity> : IEntityRepository<TEntity> 
{
    public virtual IList<TEntity> FindAll(int page, int pageSize)
    {
        return (IList<TEntity>)ActiveRecordMediator.SlicedFindAll(typeof(TEntity), (page * pageSize), pageSize);
    }
}

[ActiveRecord(Lazy = true)]
public class DocumentEntity
{
    private Guid _id;
    private IList<DocumentVersionEntity> _versions;

    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.GuidComb, "Id")]
    public virtual Guid Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    [HasAndBelongsToMany(typeof(DocumentVersionEntity), RelationType.Bag, Table = "DocumentEntriesToDocumentVersions", ColumnKey = "DocumentEntryId", ColumnRef = "DocumentVersionId", Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan, Lazy = true)]
    public virtual IList<DocumentVersionEntity> Versions
    {
        get { return _versions; }
        set { _versions = value; }
    }
}

[ActiveRecord(Lazy = true)]
public class DocumentVersionEntity
{
    private Guid _id;

    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.GuidComb, "Id")]
    public virtual Guid Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the FindAll method, all the objects in the Versions
array of the DocumentEntity are DocumentVersionEntity instead of
DocumentVersionEntityProxy and are all intialized.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cross-posted (with answers): http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/863f02fbc6ba52e8

Comment: Yeah I thought I could ask also in the Castle project group. Still, no answer to my case.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code you have your cascade behavior set to ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan:

```
 [HasAndBelongsToMany(typeof(DocumentVersionEntity),
                     RelationType.Bag,
                     Table = "DocumentEntriesToDocumentVersions", 
                     ColumnKey = "DocumentEntryId", 
                     ColumnRef = "DocumentVersionId", 
                     Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan, 
                     Lazy = true)]
    public virtual IList<DocumentVersionEntity> Versions
    {
        get { return _versions; }
        set { _versions = value; }
    }
```

This forces Nhibernate, for better or worse, to load the entire collection in order to do orphan cleanup. You'll have to get rid of the cascade behavior for it to work. This is also true of the NotFoundBehavior being set to ignore, [read here][1]: http://blog.agilejedi.com/2010/12/nhibernateactiverecord-lazy-loading.html
  [1].

Comment: Well, I tried your solution. Seemed to make sense.. but after setting all up and deleting the cascade behavior the entire entity is still being loaded. Also, this only happens on a find method like FindAll(), SlicedFindAll() and such, when I do a Get() it lazy loads correctly.

Comment: If using get does it then hibernate is working fine. Is this a web app? If so you need to make sure that the isweb config setting for ActiveRecord is set to true AND you should be using session per request:  http://using.castleproject.org/display/AR/Enable+Session+per+Request